# Ashx handler suplant WCF service comunication in just one non encripted request

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, biztalk, ashx

I'm trying to replace a WCF service based on BizTalk and as far as I know it was made using the BizTalk wizard for publishing WCF services. In order to resolve the problem I did something tricky, I exposed an ashx handler and read the soap. We want the department that consumes the service to not make any change except the url (.svc-> .ashx) and maybe another minor change like change binding. The problem I have now is the message for some reason uses more than one soap request with security tokens like:

[image]

I suppose is related to the service model configuration (credentials i think) in the WCF client,

Is there any way to force the binding in order to send just only one no encrypted-request?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to replace the BizTalk service? Why not just modify it?

Comment: Actually i don't know,  my bosses decided remove bizztalk.

Comment: This isn't really a BizTalk question then, it's a WCF/ASHX question.    Are you sure it's not the client sending the encrypted message, and BizTalk was handling decryption in the adapter and/or pipeline?